# Combining Next.JS and json-server in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, json-server

I am trying to create a docker-compose to start a demo of a Next.js App with a [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) backend.

When I move from one page to another nothing moves (using nextjs Link) until I get a timeout from backend while no request shows in the backend's logs. After that, if I reload the page it gets instantly rendered and the request does show in the backend's logs. Also client-side requests don't work at all.

Direct access to the fakeapi (http://localhost:3521/) does work with no issue.

**Docker Compose logs**

```
app_1      | event - build page: /
app_1      | wait  - compiling...
app_1      | event - compiled successfully
app_1      | event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
>>>> PAGE RELOAD
app_1      | wait  - compiling...
app_1      | event - compiled successfully
fakeapi_1  | GET /products?_page=1&_limit=50 200 10.187 ms - 83189
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: client/app
    depends_on:
      - fakeapi
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_INTERNAL_API_URI=http://fakeapi:3521
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  fakeapi:
    image: server/fakeapi
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3521:3521"
    hostname:
      fakeapi
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

**json-server package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fake-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "json-server --watch db.json --port 3521 --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.16.3"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: Tried building for production: the page is no more "stuck" but gets an "unexpected error as occured" until I reload. Client-side requests still not working.

Comment: Are you getting any requests errors in the Network tab on the browser during client-side navigations?